# How do I change the year in Unix?

Tags: redhat, terminal, date

I've looked at the man page for "date" and I can't figure out how to change the year. I know there is some string you need to create to describe the date format but how do I use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%Y is the format character for year

for example:

```
date +%Y%m%d -s "20120502"
```